# API Call happening through Service worker even we are not configured (non cached urls )

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

For the exiting project we are added progressive-web-app , but we are not cached any url or API Call, but API Call going through the Service worker .
**how to avoid the API call going through the  Service worker**

> API version we are using
>
> **service-worker** - 11.2.7
>
> **http-server** - 13.0.2
>
> **Angular**  - 11.2.7

**ngsw-config.json** configuration

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the API Call happening through the Service worker

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the API call going through the Service worker by adding the RequestHeader ngsw-bypass. See https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#bypassing-the-service-worker

You can generate such a RequestHeader with

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    "ngsw-bypass": "",
});
```

and then add it to the request, e.g.

```
this.httpClient.get(url, {headers: headers})
```